# How to replace callModule() with moduleServer function in the example below? Goal to pass data.frame from module to parent server

Tags: r, shiny, module

How do I replace the callModule() in this example with the recommended use where the moduleServer is wrapped in another function as the syntax is easier to read than the callModule.

This is the advise on the help page:

> Starting in Shiny 1.5.0, we recommend using moduleServer instead of
> callModule(), because the syntax is a little easier to understand, and
> modules created with moduleServer can be tested with testServer().

The goal is to pass the data.frame created in the module to the parent shiny server function is that it can be used there and in other modules. Any suggestions on how to improve the code below?

```
# Module UI
moduleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    actionButton(ns("generate_data"), "Generate data"),
    dataTableOutput(ns("data_table"))
  )
}

# Module server
moduleServer <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_reactive <- reactive({
    if(input$generate_data == 0) return(NULL)
    data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
  })
  output$data_table <- renderDataTable({
    data_reactive()
  })
  return(data_reactive)
}

# Parent UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  moduleUI("data_module"),
  tableOutput("data_table")
)

# Parent server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_module <- callModule(moduleServer, "data_module")
  output$data_table <- renderTable({
    data_module()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moduleServer` is the name of a function in Shiny, do not use it as a personal function. Here is how to use it:

```r
myModuleServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      data_reactive <- reactive({
        if(input$generate_data == 0) return(NULL)
        data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
      })
      output$data_table <- renderDataTable({
        data_reactive()
      })
      return(data_reactive)
    }
  )
}
```

Then call `myModuleServer("data_module")` in the main server function.